# Deployment of Docusaurus website to PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry)

Tags: cloud, static-site, docusaurus

I have created a website for documentation in my local system using website generator docusaurus.io. I am trying to figure out how to deploy it to PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry).

Which file/folder I need to deploy on Cloud, out of the bunch of files/folders?

Answer (score 1):

After you run the `yarn build` command, the `build` directory is what you need to deploy. Refer to the [deployment docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment).